# Unable to use command "flutter build ios" on a MacBook Pro 2017 with macO v13.5 (Ventura)

Tags: flutter, macos

Using Android Studio, I get the following error when launching the following command:

```
flutter build ios
```

Output:

```
Building "my bundle id" for device (ios-release)...
Automatically signing iOS for device deployment using specified development team in Xcode project: "my xcode project code"
Running pod install...                                           1,512ms
CocoaPods' output:
↳
      Preparing

    Analyzing dependencies

    Inspecting targets to integrate
      Using `ARCHS` setting to build architectures of target `Pods-Runner`: (``)
    [!] Unable to find a target named `RunnerTests` in project `Runner.xcodeproj`, did find `Runner`.

    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer/target_inspector.rb:108:in `compute_targets'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer/target_inspector.rb:40:in `compute_results'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1197:in `block (3 levels) in inspect_targets_to_integrate'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1195:in `each'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1195:in `block (2 levels) in inspect_targets_to_integrate'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1193:in `each'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1193:in `block in inspect_targets_to_integrate'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1188:in `inspect_targets_to_integrate'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:107:in `analyze'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:422:in `analyze'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:244:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:243:in `resolve_dependencies'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:162:in `install!'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:52:in `run'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.1.0/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
    /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `load'
    /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'

Error running pod install
```

My [Flutter doctor](https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/install/windows#run-flutter-doctor) is also not 100%, and I don’t know how to fix it.

```
[!] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.10.6, on macOS 13.5 22G74 darwin-x64, locale en-AU)
    ! Warning: `dart` on your path resolves to /usr/local/Cellar/dart/3.0.7/libexec/bin/dart, which is not inside your current Flutter SDK checkout at /Volumes/Macintosh
      HD/SDK/flutter. Consider adding /Volumes/Macintosh HD/SDK/flutter/bin to the front of your path.
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 14.3.1)
[✗] Chrome - develop for the web (Cannot find Chrome executable at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome)
    ! Cannot find Chrome. Try setting CHROME_EXECUTABLE to a Chrome executable.
[✓] Android Studio (version 2022.3)
[✓] Connected device (1 available)
[✓] Network resources
```

I have done a decent amount of research, but everything is suited for the new [Apple M1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_M1) and [Apple M2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_M2) chips.
My Mac uses an Intel CPU.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I *solved* this by removing the *ios* folder from Flutter.
I redownloaded it and also redownloaded [CocoaPods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CocoaPods).

It solved it for me.

Keep in mind there are different commands to install CocoaPods for different Mac cpu chips.